# Configuring slf4j and log4j correctly on WebSphere 8.5

Tags: log4j, websphere, slf4j

WHat's the correct way to configure slf4j + log4j on WebSphere 8.5.
My approach was: 
* Include slf4j-api in WEB-INF\lib of the war files of the applications
* Include the binding ja slf4j-log4j in WebSphere lib
* Include log4j.xml in JVM classpath external to the war file.

Only problem is that it doesn't work. It fails with an error on initializing. 
Guess my approach is wrong?

Thanks for any assistance!

Here's the stack trace. Note that slfj-api is found in WEB-INF\lib of the WAR file:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.spi.LoggerFactoryBinder
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:154)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:711)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$400(URLClassLoader.java:92)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:314)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:594)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:204)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:690)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:690)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:584)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:690)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:584)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:690)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:121)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:111)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:268)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:241)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:254)
    at no.klp.minside.handler.SoapLoggingHandler.<clinit>(SoapLoggingHandler.java:28)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)`enter code here`
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280)
    ... 113 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.spi.LoggerFactoryBinder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:599)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:204)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:690)
    ... 147 more
```

Comment: Why at all do you need to put stuff into the locations external to your application?

Comment: Good question, actually. I guess I think it's a good principle to let binding be decided by the runtime. And then I won't have to put the binding jar in all the war poms. I see some of our applications works without including the binding jar, and some don't. I don't understand why.. I want to understand why including in war works, and externally doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think it is an especially good principle when it comes to the packaging of Java EE applications. With several classloaders organized in a hierarchy, it is only to look for troubles not providing third-party dependencies within the application. Moreover, adjusting server classpath is a bad practice in general, not to say putting there such a specific library like slf4j-log4j.